# Alternate method for slow pandas expanding().std() window function

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any way I can speed up this code? We are trying to get the running standard deviation from a large dataset. And this step takes hours to finish. Is there any alternate method we can use?

Any alternate method in pandas or outside pandas also would be appreciated.

Tried loading the data to sqlite to do some sql , but could not successfully implement the logic. (`stddev` function itself seem not present in sqlite)

```
            df2 = df1.loc[:,['invkey','invdate','days']
                        ].fillna(0).groupby(
                            ['invkey',
                             'invdate']
                            ).expanding().std().reset_index(drop=True)
```

The code `.expanding().std()` is the time consuming step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding are generally slower. You can just manually calculate the std:

```
df['days2'] = df['days']**2
groups = (df1.loc[['invkey','invdate','days', 'days2']].fillna(0)
             .groupby(['invkey', 'invdate']
         )


counts = groups['days'].cumcount()+1
means = groups['days'].cumsum()/counts
square_sums = groups['days2'].cumsum()

out = np.sqrt((square_sums - counts*means**2)/(counts-1))
```

Test on my system shows this is about 4x faster than `groupby().expanding().std()` on 100M rows.

Comment: This is really great.. This works much faster and i got the same results as the original one(Except the 5th or 6th decimal difference.). But somehow the data sorting is changed compared to the old one. Could this be at `np.sqrt`? Or when i converted the `out` to a dataframe?